# wcstok() not working correctly?

Tags: c

I'm trying to get each line in a loop for a `wchar_t` string using `wcstok()`, that string is supposed to contain at least two lines, the latest 'wcstok(0, L"\n")' is getting always null result and I'm getting the value of `i` using `printf` as 1 only instead of 2 or higher, but the problem got solved when doing `#if 0` instead of `#if 1`.
this is the code below:

```
     wchar_t* w;
     wchar_t* line;
     int j;
     wchar_t**** lines;
     int** linescount;
       ......
     int i=0;
#if 1 //problem get solved when changing to #if 0
     line = wcstok(w, L"\n");
     do{
     ((*linescount)[j])++;
     }while(line=wcstok(0, L"\n"));
     (*lines)[annex] = calloc(sizeof(wchar_t**), (*linescount)[j]);
#endif
     line = wcstok(w, L"\n");
     do{
#if 1 //problem get solved when changing to #if 0
      (*lines)[j][i] = calloc(sizeof(wchar_t*), wcslen(line)+1);
      wcscpy((*lines)[j][i], line);
#endif
      i++;
     }while(line=wcstok(0, L"\n"));
     printf("i = %d\n", i); /*prints the i value to check if the latest line=wcstok(0, L"\n") worked correctly or not*/
```

so what's supposed the cause of this problem? and how can I solve it? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wcstok modifies the string passed in as argument so once you have run your loop to count lines the buffer is basically kaputt.

It seems like overkill to use wcstok to count lines when you easily could just loop through the buffer counting number of \n.

Comment: so what's the cause of problem here? is it that wcstok() loop was executed another time? or what exactly?

Comment: since the buffer has been modified in your first #if 1 the second time you write `line = wcstok(w, L"\n");` it will not work properly.

Comment: @user3457200 well, the *root* cause of the problem  is you don't understand what `wcstok()` *does*. It replaces a discovered delimiter with a null char. Making a second pass across a data buffer looking for the very thing the prior pass just obliterated is naturally not going to find what is now-gone, thus NULL is returned. For this task, wcstok isn't needed in the first place, but if you do use it, it should be only the second pass, not the first. Just walk the string and count newlines for the first pass, and don't forget, the last string may *not* end with one.

Comment: or to add to @WhozCraigs answer you can use realloc to dynamically increase the number of pointers to the strings as you read it in instead of doing a first pass to count lines.

Comment: Thank you very much! my problem got solved, that's really helpful! +1.